# viewForAnnotation sometimes can't get custom MKAnnotation class and render it properly

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have different classes (MKAnnotation subclass) that represent map annotations.
I load them on the map and it's fine but when I move or zoom map pins starts to loosing their image.
When I pan map `viewForAnnotation` is called but pin that is `BluePin` class for example not anymore get in it's `if` block and as a result it renders the last annotation from `viewForAnnotation` with default pin image (green).
**UPDATE**
I just realised that code actually get in each IF properly but never get in nested IF so this line of code make some issues:

```
var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("blue")
            if (annotationView == nil) { ... after zoom/pan never get here }...
```

What can be the issue here:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {            
            return nil
        }
if(annotation.isKindOfClass(BluePin)){

            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("blue")
            if (annotationView == nil) {
                annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "blue")
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true;

                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "blue")

                return annotationView
            }
        } else if(annotation.isKindOfClass(RedPin)){

            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("red")
            if (annotationView == nil) {
                annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "red")
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true;                                
                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "red")

                return annotationView
            }
        }


            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("def") as? MKPinAnnotationView
            if pinView == nil {
                pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "def")                
                pinView!.pinColor = .Green

            }
            else {
                pinView!.annotation = annotation
            }

            return pinView
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` method will return a previously-created view (if any) that is not currently being used for display (this is the whole point of using this method so that you get view re-use).

When the method does find a view that can be re-used, it will return that view and so the result will be non-`nil`.

When you zoom/pan the map, some annotations go out of view and new ones come into view.  The ones that come into view can now re-use the views of the annotations  no longer visible.  So `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` returns a non-`nil` result.

The current code isn't handling the case where `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` returns non-`nil` for the blue and red pins and so *execution continues with the next statement after the big `if` block* which is `var pinView = mapView...` which then creates the default green pin view.

The code needs to be modified to handle the cases where `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` returns non-`nil` for the blue and red pins:

```
    if(annotation.isKindOfClass(BluePin)) {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("blue")
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "blue")
            annotationView.canShowCallout = true;
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "blue")
        } else {
            //handle blue view re-use...
            annotationView.annotation = annotation
        }

        //move return to after the if-else...
        return annotationView
    }
    else if(annotation.isKindOfClass(RedPin)) {

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("red")
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "red")
            annotationView.canShowCallout = true;
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "red")
        } else {
            //handle red view re-use...
            annotationView.annotation = annotation
        }

        //move return to after the if-else...
        return annotationView
    }
```

Comment: Instead of 'annotation.isKindOfClass' compare for annotation identifier, that's a better approach.